# How to take backup of Visual studio 2010 from C Drive at the time of Formatting the System?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am planning to install windows 8.1 from windows 8 but i want  backup of visual studio ,without installing it again in windows 8.1 how can i do it ?

Comment: Why not just run an in-place upgrade, rather than a clean install?

Comment: Won't work, the registry is very important.  Do *not* format the drive, the Windows 8.1 installer doesn't require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through all the trouble you can simply install VS 2010 after u finish formatting the system. You may take a back up of the project folder where u have your projects. By default it in the location C:\Users\Your_Usernam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects

And once you done with the installation of Window 8.1 reinstall VS 2010 or VS 2012 or VS 2013 and use the back up of your projects folder.

Comment: Yeah that is fine by taking the projects back up but is there any way not to reinstall vs again in windows 8.1 ?

Comment: The VS2010 installation will install and register a whole heap of class libraries, components and other "funky" stuff that it is not a simple thing to do.

You would have to back up registry settings, all sorts of things from Windows System folders.

There is no quick solution to it... As said, a simple reinstall is by far the quickest...AND SAFEST... way to go.

Comment: okay budd i thought there might be a way to do so .. any way i will install vs2010 again .. Thanks .

Comment: Even if you go through all the backing up process of the registries even then you will have to specifically install a few more things and the chances of everything working fine after going through all the trouble is still negligible..

Comment: Yup i got it . Thanks for the solutions .

Comment: If you feel this to be the answer you were looking for, the click on the up arrow button in the beginning of the answer. This would help others in locating the answer..

Comment: I have only 14 reputation budd !!!

Comment: No issues buddy. It was just an info for you. Might be useful for you in the future.

Comment: I downloaded 20 gb of data to install all vs features. I dont want to download that again because thats takes too long. What should i do

Answer (score 0):

IMHO , it would be far simpler to reinstall and I would take the opportunity to install 2012/2013 and have a nice clean install.

ETA: Why do you need to keep the current install?